# Why is tf.concat much slower than np.concatenate and the "append" of the native python list? Should we avoid if possible?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, tensorflow

I'm implementing a math library using Tensorflow, which internally calls `tf.concat` quite often. I was curious about the speed of `tf.concat`. For testing, I created the following simple code to compare the speed of `tf.concat`, `np.concatenate` and the `append` method for native python lists. Of course, in the following example case, we can use `tf.range` and `np.arange` for better efficiency. In my case, I wanted to check the speed of `tf.concat` since in the actual math library, I need to arbitrarily add elements.

```
#/usr/bin/python3
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np  
import time

x_tf = tf.constant([], dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
x_np = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
x_list = []
limit = 10000

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(limit):
    x_list.append(np.float32(i))
print("Elapsed time: {0}".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(limit):
    x_np = np.concatenate((x_np, [i]), axis=0)
print("Elapsed time: {0}".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(limit):
    x_tf = tf.concat((x_tf, [i]), axis=0)
print("Elapsed time: {0}".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

When I tested using both CPUs and GPUs, the Tensorflow version was slowest, and the numpy version was the next slowest. The native python array was the fastest by a large margin. The following is the result.

```
2021-01-02 22:00:20.438159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 11271 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
Elapsed time: 0.004985332489013672
Elapsed time: 0.06686067581176758
Elapsed time: 2.0447843074798584
```

Because the difference in speed is immense, it seems that it may be better to avoid using tf.concat if possible. In this case, it seems that it's better to do all the processing using the Native Python list, and only converting the final list into a Tensor.

Could anyone tell me whether I'm understanding correctly and give some suggestions or advice?

Comment: tensorflow and numpy functions do not do the same thing, so it makes no sense to make these comparisons

Answer (score 1):

`np.concatenate` is growing an array, which is not the same thing as appending to a list; a new memory block must be allocated with n+1 size in each pass of your loop, so naturally if you are inserting one item at a time, a list `append` will be faster.

Numpy and tensorflow are optimized for array or tensor operations. For example you could create the same numpy array without a loop: `np_array = np.arange(limit)`, which will be **much** faster that your `append`loop.